# MVVM: custom class for grid objects that is only accessible by code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm writing a C# UI and trying to follow the MVVM pattern. My design consists of a grid representing a join of two objects in the database, some text fields, and some buttons.

I've been successful binding the data context of the xaml to my view model code, and my code-behind (.xaml.cs) is very minimal. I've done this by adding a class called `GridObjs` to hold the grid objects (i.e. objects with properties specific to the UI that aren't members of the model layer objects). Unfortunately, however, this approach requires that I expose my `GridObjs` class publicly in order for it to be used by the .xaml.cs.

Is there a solution that allows me to hide `GridObjs` but also allows it to be accessible by the .xaml.cs?

Comment: Are you using any of the available MVVM libraries or writing your own?

Comment: @Darek - I'm writing my own (cannot post code, though).

Comment: Make the class in .xaml.cs internal instead of public.